# Rendenização de imagem demorada lado cliente

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, processamento-de-imagens, encode

Utilizo em uma página web imagens que são carregadas a partir de um campo do tipo `blob` no *Firebird*. As imagens abrem em um modal, totalmente carregadas, ou seja, sem utilizar *thumbnails*, e quando o usuário clica em uma dessas imagens, a imagem é redimensionada em um tamanho maior e ocupa a tela toda.

Porém este processo para abrir a imagem está demorando, apesar do arquivo `.png` ou de outro formato de imagem já estar carregado no lado do cliente. Utilizo no `php` o base64_encode, e isso retorna um texto enorme para ser renderizado no elemento `img` no lado do cliente, acredito que seja isso, porém não encontrei outra maneira a não ser de exibir para o usuário que a imagem está carregando.

Screen:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: porque você não faz upload da imagem e salva o link dela no banco de dados ? salvar imagens no banco de dados e perigoso, se  o banco corromper você perde as imagens e toda vez que você for chamar uma foto é uma requisição ao banco.

Comment: Não tem uma maneira de deixar o carregamento mais rápido sem armazenar no computador mas sim no banco de dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Controller da sua aplicação você pode criar um método para pegar a imagem a partir do banco de dados e chamar no `src` da sua imagem dessa maneira, por exemplo, `localhost/meuprojeto/controller/metodo?imagem={id_imagem}`, dessa maneira não demora para rendenizar e não ocorre o risco de travar o navegador do usuário.

Comment: Na época fizemos dessa maneira e funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: Beleza. Obrigado.